# is there an easy way to get output of system commands into a string?

Tags: c++

Is there an easy way to get output of system commands into a string in C++?

Heres and example of what I mean, trying to get the epoch into a string.
It doesnt work of course.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string t = system("date +%s");
    cout << "Time " << t << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Why not just use `strftime` and `time`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/4926357

Comment: what does `syetem()` return?

Comment: system returns an integer, 0 for success, -1 for fail. Its not the output of the system command.

Comment: @j0h: it doesn't return only `1` or `0` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx

Comment: @Raindrop7 I shouls specify this is a Linux system.

Answer (score 3):

For that specific task you probably want to use `time` and `ctime` (or something similar).

For the more general case, see `popen` (or, on Microsoft compilers, `_popen`). This doesn't return a string directly; it returns a `FILE *`, which you can then read like you would a file.